# Converting from a xml parsed list to character in R

Tags: xml, r

I have read and parsed a *url* using *htmlParse()*.

I have used *xpathApply* to filter out and get the exact content that I want.

I want to convert the list created into character. When I try to convert I get this error:

```
"<pointer: 0x000000001673db70>"
```

I am assuming that the parsed content is pointed in the main object using pointers.

The content that I want might have some some XML syntax in it, so xmlValue will do no good.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example demonstrating the issue you are having.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `saveXML` to convert the internal nodes to characters:

```
library(XML)
appUrl <- 'http://cran.r-project.org/'
doc <- htmlParse(appUrl)
out1 <- xpathSApply(doc, "//*/frame")
out2 <- xpathSApply(doc, "//*/frame", saveXML)
> str(out1)
List of 3
 $ :Classes 'XMLInternalElementNode', 'XMLInternalNode', 'XMLAbstractNode' <externalptr> 
 $ :Classes 'XMLInternalElementNode', 'XMLInternalNode', 'XMLAbstractNode' <externalptr> 
 $ :Classes 'XMLInternalElementNode', 'XMLInternalNode', 'XMLAbstractNode' <externalptr> 
> str(out2)
 chr [1:3] "<frame src=\"logo.html\" name=\"logo\" frameborder=\"0\"/>" ...
```